# How To Move Bones Back Into Original Position After Applying Shape Key

Tags: rigging, bones, shape-keys

i'm trying out bones and rigging and i've run into a little problem. I used 2 bones to move the blender monkey's ear and applied that as a shape key. However, the bones are now in that bent position but I want them in the original position so I can apply a different shape key. Is there any way to move it back in place without manually doing so or deleting the shape key? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it? I believe they have the same solution but this is a more niche case? I'm new to this whole "StackExchange" scene so I don't know what the proper etiquette or procedure is. Should I delete this post?

Comment: Please [don't delete duplicates](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

- Select the armature and go back into pose mode.
- Select the bones you want to reset and hit alt-r to reset rotation
  and alt-g to reset position

Comment: Thanks for the response.What keys do I need to press for the "-"? Because just pressing "r" is the rotation key bind. I'm new to Blender so I'm not that familiar with all the key binds and stuff.

Comment: Nevermind, it works with "Alt-g", "Alt-r", and "Alt-s". Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't notice that it didnt render my text right. I edited the answer to make it more clear